# 2nd jQuery function Cancelling out 1st one

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, autoplay

I tried by myself, I really did. Read tons of forum posts, tried code pens, fiddles and the whole 9. I've essentially wasted 3 days. I'm working on a client's site, so time is of the essence. I know there are brilliant coders here.

I implemented a jquery code for making my videos stop playing when I close a modal. Here is that code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
        var memory = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(memory);
    });
});
```

(I'm using Wordpress so that's why I have to do the first line like that.)

Anyway that worked great, videos stop playing when you shut the modal. But then I wanted to use a video poster image, and to avoid the cumbersome double-click, it needs a defer autoplay (halts video from autoplaying on page load, waits till poster image is clicked.) Here is the code I always use for that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $('.vidposter').on('click', function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var videoSRC = element.attr('data-videoSRC');
    var iframe = '<iframe width="700" height="394" src="'+videoSRC+'"></iframe>';
    element.html(iframe);
    });
});
```

In case you need to see it, here is the HTML:

```
  <div align="center"><div class="vidposter" data-videoSRC="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123456789?autoplay=1"><img src="http://blahblahsite.com/images/image.jpg" style="cursor:pointer"></div></div>
```

PROBLEM:

Both pieces of jquery work great alone. When I upload the second script, it gets ignored. Or when I attempt a combined one, the second function fails.

My attempt at combining:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.vidposter').on('click', function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var videoSRC = element.attr('data-videoSRC');
        var iframe = '<iframe width="700" height="394" src="'+videoSRC+'"></iframe>';
        element.html(iframe);
    });

    $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
        var memory = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(memory);
    });
});
```

Am I combining them wrong?? Do I need to rewrite something?

FYI: What happens is the "vid poster + defer autoplay" works, but the "stop video on modal close" not only gets ignored, it starts the video over from the beginning.

Comment: Do you have a live demo??

Comment: i posted an answer. you didn't provided the full codes, but it was my guess. also if i understood `stop` and `pause` wrong, just search for "stop(or pause) iframe video" and "stop(or pause) video tag" to find the codes for it.

Comment: Hi thank you for the responses! what do you mean by I didn't provide full codes? I pasted exactly what I'm using. Also: I'm studying your answer right now. Are you saying that in the first function, video and iframe conflict? That code works fine till I introduce the second function (modal close).

Comment: @brandydoll yes but i don't really know that you're using "stop videos on modal close" on wich video. there is no video in your posted question. you use it probably on some video on some modal, but you didn't post modal and video. (usage of first function)

Comment: @brandydoll i mean, the html before you decided to use poster image.

Answer (score 0):

One of your codes is using `video` tags for videos , and another uses `iframe` tags for videos.

the first one want to pause `video` tag of second one, but second one uses `iframe` tag instead.

they are inconsistent with each other. pausing videos with `video` tags are different than `iframe` tags.

For stop videos , you should check if it is `iframe` or `normal video`. and stop video for each case separately.

So change:

```
    var memory = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(memory);
```

to:

```
if($(this).find('iframe')[0]){
        var iframe = $(this).find('iframe')[0];
        try{
          var vid = $(iframe).contents().find(this)[0];
          if (vid) {vid.pause();vid.currentTime = 0;}
        }catch(e){console.log(e);}
        //for vimeo videos
        if(iframe.contentWindow)iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"method":"unload"}', '*');
    }
    else if($(this).find('video')[0]){
        var memory = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(memory);
    }
```

also if you want pause instead of stop, remove `vid.currentTime = 0;` and change `"method":"unload"` to `"method":"pause"`

Comment: Thank you for all this input. Apparently we're not supposed to say thank you on here or smile or anything, but that is foreign to me. Just picture a smiley face here: Now about your answer...just so I am clear, what is this going to do? Pause the video? I want it to stop entirely if the modal is closed.

Comment: Oh cool :)   I changed that line but it didnt work. I will come back online tomorrow. How do I thank you or give you points or whatever?

Comment: @brandydoll here is the final one : https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/orvedy?editors=0010 (line 32 and 33 are changed. the problem was your first code :p)

Comment: @brandydoll previous code should work, but if it didn't, try this as well : https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/qzWVzm?editors=0010

Comment: Hi! I cant wait to get home tonight and try this! I will let you know :p

Comment: oh my god it worked! Lol you are the BESSTTTTTTTTT :D

Comment: Is there a way to favorite you for future projects? (paid of course)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :p actually for paid works, i won't accept some types of projects (for religious reasons) (for example projects related to alcohol, drugs, musics, etc). But for other projects, you can mention me on stackoverflow (for example here), or mail me (ya3ya63@gmail.com). (I'm not active on social media, sorry about that)

Comment: Ok I will save your info my friend. No cannabis related stuff if I need to hire. ;) I don't care that we're not allowed to say it - Thank you so much! You're briIliant, truly. I will get a lot of mileage out of this code. I applied it to a whole bunch of stuff already. I'm going to make a new post now about a tiny rollover question lol. See you around!

Comment: @brandydoll :p Thanks, Glad it helped and I will be happy to help in future as well :D

Comment: @brandydoll you should only remove every `console.log` lines (they are for debugging), just like this: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/VJYxzW

Comment: @brandydoll haha, sorry about refresh :p do you have skype, or facebook? if so let's continue chat on there.

Comment: @brandydoll my skype id is: live:ya3ya6_1 and my skype name is "yaya sh".. well it's 6:30 am here and i'm' trying to finish my project (sleepy :p) so time difference is about 8:30 hours. after you came back, drop me a message in skype and i will respond (i'm online) if i wasn't sleep :p

Comment: Hi! When is the next time you will be on skype or able to take a look?

Comment: P.S. I deleted the extra msgs here

Comment: @brandydoll Hi. i'm free from now till next 7 hours. what time is suitable for you?

Comment: Yipeeeeeeeee :) :) :) ok lemme write up the question on here (new thread), and get on skype...

Comment: @brandydoll ok :)